# 8 bit hex string to signed integer

Tags: objective-c, hex, nsscanner

I have an 8 bit Hex Value like: "FB" (-5). Now I need an signed integer value for this hex. The NSScanner don't work on this place, because you need an 4 Byte hex value, to get it negative. Before I start some bit manipulation, maybe someone of you know the better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type casting is not safe but you really need it.

```
NSString *tempNumber = @"FB";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tempNumber];
unsigned int temp;
[scanner scanHexInt:&temp];
int actualInt = (char)temp; //why char because you have 8 bit integer
NSLog(@"%@:%d:%d",tempNumber, temp, actualInt);
```

**Console output: `FB:251:-5`**

Comment: One more thing. I also have an 16 bit Int, that also can be negativ. 
How to do that in this case? Cast would not work anymore?

Comment: Maybe I really need to go the other way and negate the value and then increment 1 and such a stuff?

Comment: For `16 bit` integer you can cast it to `short int` which is '16 bit` (tested on 32 bit simulator and 64 bit simulator). Although the size of `short int` depends upon the compiler implementation. In general it's `short int <= int <= long int`